# How to inject a reply into the twitter's reply section?

Tags: javascript, twitter, dom-manipulation, openai-api

I am creating a browser extension that automatically generates a reply to the selected tweet.
The problem I am facing is that whenever I try to inject the reply into the reply section, the value is not stored in the twitter's server and the reply button is dimmed out.

[image]

Here's the code I used to do this:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr")[0].getElementsByTagName("span");

if (elements.length === 0) {
      return;
}
  
const element = elements[0];

document.getElementsByClassName("public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr")[0].focus();

const span = `<span data-text="true">${content}</span>`

element.innerHTML = span;
```

I need to manipulate the dom element of reply section and need to successfully reply with the generated context to a tweet.

Comment: Use twitter API

Comment: I'm not using Twitter, so I might be off here, but have you tried getting the `input` / `textarea` which normally holds the reply, and setting its `value` attribute to whatever you want to post as a reply? Something like `var reply = document.querySelector("<textholderSelectorHere>"); if(reply.length) { reply.value = "lorem ipsum sit dolor amet"; }`

Answer (score 3):

I guess the tweet button is subscribed to keyboard/mouse events you'd have to add synthetic event for this to work.

```js
const e = document.getElementsByClassName("class you want to select")[0]
e.textContent = "test"
e.click()
e.dispatchEvent(new Event("input", {bubbles: true}))
```

[I tried it for myself and it works as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC7x1.png)

---

Follow me on Twitter [@bhavinkamani_](https://twitter.com/bhavinkamani_)